# RegEx to match numbers, characters and < in Kotlin

Tags: regex, kotlin

I need to parse some passports and ID cards, with Strings such as

```
val text = "P<GBRSTONE<<SARAH<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<\n" +
                    "0689349234GBR3708248F1601013<<<<<<<<<<<<<<06"
```

(yes, two rows)
and I need to validate the text first because it can only contain capital letters, digits, `<` and newline characters.

I'm using https://regexr.com/ and I've tried expressions such as `[A-Z0-9<{\n}"]` but when I try to validate my text using `fun Mrz.validChars(): Regex = Regex("/[A-Z0-9<{\n}]")` always returns `false`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The first `/` in the pattern matches a `/`, did you intend to match it? `c` is an alphanumeric char BTW.

Comment: Yes, because the string will have `\n` (hence the two or three lines of the string). The problem is that if I enter that string in regerx.com it matches everything, but not in Kotlin: the `validChars` method returns false

Comment: `\n` is ok, why `/`? You have no `{` and `}` in the string, why are they in the pattern?

Comment: Try `"[A-Za-z0-9<\n]+".toRegex().matches(text)` if you want to make sure the whole string only consists of ASCII alphanumeric chars, `<` or a newline. See [demo](https://rextester.com/WFFVW63057)

Comment: Ok I will try that, because in tried exactly the same but without the + and it didn't work. Thanks!

Comment: Well, it is not the same, my suggestion matches all ASCII letters, did you mean that you want to match all *uppercase* but only one lowercase `c`  letter? Then you need `"[A-Zc0-9<\n]+"`

Comment: I need to match capital letters, numbers, < (could be several occurrences just like in the shown string) and \n because of the several lines

Comment: Then you need just `"[A-Z0-9<\n]+"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use

```
val text = "P<GBRSTONE<<SARAH<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<\n" +
                "0689349234GBR3708248F1601013<<<<<<<<<<<<<<06"
println("[A-Z0-9<\n]+".toRegex().matches(text))
```

See the [online demo](https://rextester.com/BPFLLU52006)

The `[A-Z0-9<\n]+` pattern matches one or more occurrences of ASCII uppercase letters, digits, `<` or newline and `matches()` ensures the whole string match (i.e. it cannot contain any other characters).